# problem in using list in game maker studio

Tags: list, for-loop, game-maker-studio-2

I am new to the game maker. I created a list and I want to compare all the data in the list with a specific value. I used the following code:

```
for(var i=0;i<ds_list_size(lst);i++;)
{
    if ds_list_find_value(lst,i)>tmp
       ds_list_replace(lst,i,ds_list_find_value(lst,i)-1);
}
```

and I face the following error:

> Push :: Execution Error - Variable Get -1.lst(100001, -1)
>   at
>   gml_Object_object0_RightButtonPressed_1 (line 21) -     for(var i=0;i

where is my problem?

Thanks all.

Comment: As error indicates, the "lst" variable is not set on the calling object at all. You would want to fix that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your first for loop i = 0; and when the first entry in the list is smaller than tmp it tries to replace the first place in the list with a not existing one. so you could either check if its the first entry of the list with

```
if ( i == 0 ) { }
```

or your could start the for loop from the second entry with

```
for(var i=1;i<ds_list_size(lst);i++;)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `;` at the end of `i++;` is unnecessary, you only need to use `;` in a for-loop as seperator.

GML gives more freedom to common C# rules though (like how there are no brackets needed around an if-condition), so perhaps that's allowed.

Another possibility might be that the index is out of range at `ds_list_replace()`

Comment: Thanks Steven for your answer.
as you said there is no problem for the semicolon and I think it is not possible for the ds_list_replace goes out of range because the range of the for is between 0 to (ds_lis_size(lst)-1)